# Best practices for mounting Linux filesystems on OS X over the Internet

Tags: unix, macos, mount

Before I ask my question, an impassioned plea. Please don't let this devolve into a "use the command-line or GTFO" flamewar. Yes, I know about scp and friends.

I have a VPS running Ubuntu and I'd like to mount one of its filesystems on my Mac so I can use all my local tools and copy files via finder, etc.

I'm using Fuse/MacFusion now, and it's particularly slow.

Any better way?

Comment: I thought OS X supported mounting volumes over SSH natively...

Comment: scp is not for mounting a file system...

Comment: And are you asking for specific products to use for mounting non-native filesystems to your Mac? Because that might get this closed as a shopping question, especially if you're disregarding anything that uses the command line or script to mount.

Comment: I think he means MacFUSE SSHFS.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - I'll look into that.

Comment: @Bart - Not looking for anything commercial, looking for best practices on mounting a Linux filesystem on my Mac over the net.  The comment about using the command line was trying to short circuit people telling me to move files via scp/sftp instead of remote mounting.

Comment: @cjc - Sorry, I should have been more specific... I'm front-ending MacFUSE via the [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) app.

Comment: Now that the question has migrated, I expect you'll get the opposite of "use the command-line or GTFO" -- the command line is a great tool to fall back on when necessary, but Mac users would generally *prefer* a solution that works in the Finder. I wish I knew one to post as an answer for you, but welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

First, set up a VPN connection between the VPS and your Mac. Something like OpenVPN is fine (the TunnelBlick Mac client works well, at least up through Snow Leopard).

Second, set up the VPS as an AFP server using the "netatalk" package.  Something like `sudo apt-get install netatalk`.  AFP is the native Mac network filesystem.  Configure it to your situation.

At this point, you can establish the VPN connection between the VPS and the Mac, and then find and mount the AFP volumes from the VPS in your Finder.

An alternative would be to use something like MacFUSE and SSHFS, but using AFP is more "native" and will show up better in Finder.

Comment: I already use TunnleBlick to drive all traffic through my VPS when I'm on the road, so this has real possibilities.  Thanks.

Comment: I have a CentOS box at home from which I occasionally mount directories on my Macbook.  It works decently enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup WebDAV on the VPS (there are various tutorials depending on the Ubuntu version available on the internet), and then use Finder, which has native support for it to access it. Just make sure that you use WebDAV over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

[Expandrive](http://nolobe.com/interarchy/) or [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) or [Interarchy](http://nolobe.com/interarchy/).

Those are the easiest and most Mac friendly ways.